# How to render partials from unrelated controllers in one view....almost Amazon style

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, rendering, partial-views

How can we render many partials from different controllers into one view?
The local variables of each partial are calculated separately in different and independent controllers.

What I really have to make things more specific, is a home layout, and in that layout that has dynamic content, there's a partial that only handles site wide news announcements, and these are independently updated.

I know a quick hack such like:

```
render :partial => '/news', :locals=> {@news = News.last}
```

but I want something more "correct". Like I've been reading about :templates rendering but i'm not sure how it works exactly in Rails 3.1.

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2.2.3 Rendering an Action’s Template from Another Controller
What if you want to render a template from an entirely different controller from the one that contains the action code? You can also do that with render, which accepts the full path (relative to app/views) of the template to render. For example, if you’re running code in an AdminProductsController that lives in app/controllers/admin, you can render the results of an action to a template in app/views/products this way:

render 'products/show'
Rails knows that this view belongs to a different controller because of the embedded slash character in the string. If you want to be explicit, you can use the :template option (which was required on Rails 2.2 and earlier):

render :template => 'products/show'

Sources: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-content_for

Should have read in more details.